# How to Convert a Entity to a List

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, entity

I have an entity with only boolean Properties:

```cs
namespace MyProject.Entities
{
    public class MyEntity
    {
        
        public bool Bool2 { get; set; }
        public bool Bool2 { get; set; }
        public bool Bool2 { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Now I want do this:

```cs
using MyProject.Entities
namespace MyProject
{
    public class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity()
            {
                Bool1=true,
                Bool2=false,
                Bool3=false
            }
            List<bool> Bool = myEntity.ToList(); //this doesn't run!
        }
    }
}
```

I need it first as Model, course I work in asp.net core mvc, and I get this model from a razor page. But now I need it as a list to check every prop.
Can anyone help me?

The output that I need is a List with these three Booleans

Comment: Not quite following. You have a class (`MyEntity`) that has three identically named Boolean properties (I'm assuming this does not compile). Then you have another class `ProductViewFilterModel`. Are they related? The easiest way to do what I think you may be talking about is to create a method (or read-only property) on `MyEntity` that returns a list of bools that represent its properties. Otherwise, you could use Reflection

Comment: Sry, i forgot to change one Word, now u understand it better? What u mean with Reflection?

Comment: The internet has search engines, try looking for "C# Reflection". Reflection allows you to look at a type, or an instance of a type and see inside it. So, for example,  you could look at the `MyEntity` type, and see it's properties. It can also look at an instance of a type and see the values of those properties. However, it would be more efficient to create a method on `MyEntity` (called `ToList` possibly) that builds a `List<bool>` from the properties and returns it

Comment: Was my answer of any use to you?

Comment: Yes it helped, tanks ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I'm talking about in the comments.  First a class (with *different* property names - it does compile).  I've added a `ToBoolList` method.

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public bool Bool1 { get; set; }
    public bool Bool2 { get; set; }
    public bool Bool3 { get; set; }

    public List<bool> ToBoolList()
    {
        return new List<bool> { Bool1, Bool2, Bool3 };
    }
}
```

To test this, run:

```
var testEntity = new MyEntity { Bool1 = true, Bool2 = false, Bool3 = true };
var boolList = testEntity.ToBoolList();
```

It will return a `List<bool>` containing `true`, `false` and `true`.

To do it with reflection, first you need to get the type of `MyEntity`, then its public instance properties, filtered so that only `bool`s are returned.  Finally, the code below gets each property's `GetMethod` and invokes it on the the object.

```
var testEntity = new MyEntity { Bool1 = true, Bool2 = false, Bool3 = true };
var entType = typeof(MyEntity);
var entProps = entType.GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
var boolProps = entProps.Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(bool) && p.CanRead);
var boolReflectList = boolProps.Select(p => p.GetGetMethod().Invoke(testEntity, null)).Cast<bool>().ToList();
```

It also returns a `List<bool>` containing `true`, `false` and `true`.  The first example should execute much faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the following code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity()
            {
                Bool1=true,
                Bool2=false,
                Bool3=false
            }
            List<bool> Bool = myEntity.GetType().GetProperties().Select(s=>s.GetValue(myEntity)).ToList();
        }
```

result:
[image]